# AJAX not using the success handler function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Hi I have an issue with my AJAX returning a JSON object, as it does not seem to be using the success handler function, and falls straight into the error handler.

The thing that I don't understand is, the same AJAX script will successfully return the JSON object of another API.

The code I am using is this

> ```
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>          $.ajax({
>             type: "GET",
>             dataType: "jsonp",
>             url: "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=soccer&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
>             success: function (flikrData) {
>                 console.log(flikrData);
>                     document.writeln("<Table style='width:1000px; height:auto; text-align:center; margin:auto; background-color:lightblue;'>");
>                     document.write("<tr>");
>                     for (var ini = 0; ini <= flikrData.items.length; ini++) {
>                         document.write("<tr>");
>                         document.write("<td>");
>                         document.writeln("Title: " + flikrData.items[ini].title + "Author: " + flikrData.items[ini].author + "Author ID: " + flikrData.items[ini].author_id + "Date Taken: " + flikrData.items[ini].date_taken + "Description: " + flikrData.items[ini].description + "Link: " + flikrData.items[ini].link + flikrData.items[ini].media.m + "Tags: " + flikrData.items[ini].tags);
>                         document.write("</td>");
>                         document.write("</tr>");
>                     };
>                     document.write("<tr>");
>                     document.writeln("</Table>");
>             },
>             error: function (jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
>                 console.log(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown);
>             }
>         });
>     });
> </script>
> ```

Now the above works correctly and was using it as a proof of concept.

The only difference from the above to the real one, which I included an altered version below to show the difference in the format, is that the below one seems to be an exposed webservice. Does that mean I have to handle the JSON object differently?

```
http://test.net.au/Services/ClientApi.svc/listEventsByCustomer?customerId=" + customerID + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?"
```

I have tried many different variations of the above as suggested by people from similar questions, such as `jsonp: '$callback'`, `?callback=?`, `&callback=?` but none have seemed to work.

The error function is producing the following result in the Chrome Console.

```
{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

Which from what I understand means that it has worked... I can even see the JSON object being returned in Fiddler, but it just won't trigger the success handler.

I have tested the actual link in Jsonlint and it has verified that it is indeed a JSON object.

Does anybody have any ideas

> [OperationContract]
>     [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet(UriTemplate = "getCustomerById?customerId={customerId}",
>     [RespnseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
>     Customer GetCustomerById(Guid customerId);

Comment: JSONP is not the same as JSON.

Comment: JSONP is JSON wrapped with `<callbackname>(...)`.

Comment: Anyways, don't use `document.write`, ever. Append things via `$.appendTo` [or use templating better, but that is a step further].

Comment: Ah, [your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/gaAd3/).

Comment: Yeah I understand that but does I thought the differences were contained to `dataType: "jsonp"` and the `&callback=?` are there additional aspects that i should be taking into account?

Comment: @moonwave99 Duly noted, I will use that from now on, I just wanted to put something on the screen. That is the code that is supposed to work, it is when i swap it out for the real URL that it doesn't

Comment: The server code has to be written a little differently if the client is using `jsonp` rather than `json`. In PHP, for instance, you must do: `echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($result).')';` instead of `echo json_encode($result);`.

Comment: @Barmar I dont have any say in how the server side was developed but I cant use JSON because of the cross domain issue. I can see the JSON object being returned I just cannot access it. If the server were not set up to recieve JSONP requests would it not deny the connection as it violates the cross domain constraint?

Comment: Cross-domain restrictions are implemented by the browser, not the server. If the server doesn't implement JSONP, you'll need to use a local proxy to get the data. Take a look at Simple PHP Proxy.

Comment: @Barmar Ok I understand that, but I think what is confusing me is that I am still getting data back but the script is just not dealing with it, if the server didn't implement jsonp would it still respond to the request?

Comment: The server doesn't know it's a JSONP request. It's just an HTTP request, and it responds to it, sending JSON data. But your code is expecting JSONP data, and when the response doesn't parse as JSONP, it reports it as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly is a weird error. My guess is that the ajax handler is expecting a different response type, and when it receives the 'wrong' type it throws an error.

So I'd guess the problem lies with using JSONP with that server and the callback. Are you sure that server is able to respond to JSONP requests?